# How execute exe file from sql agent or job?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-agent-job

I don't want to hit the database frequently based on page request, so I planned to create a xml file using separate C# coding [exe file] & put in the common path to access from different page/project, which will do the hitting stuff's daily morning, so can you explain how do I execute exe file from sql job or agent by scheduled manner?

My scenario: database table will be updated only once, so I am going for a XML/txt file.

Thanks,
S.Venkatesh

Comment: not sure i understand the question, but would love to see some answers!

Comment: You should be using Task Scheduler in windows for starting your app.

Answer (score 31):

Executable and batch files may be added to a job as step ([MSDN Implement Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187056.aspx)).

1. Create a job
2. Add a new step

2.1 set "Operating system(CmdExec)" as type

2.2 set the executable path

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you must do it in JOB: [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
xp_cmdshell execute as nonadmin!

```
DECLARE @command varchar(8000)
SET @command = 'C:\MyProgram' 
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @command
```

But you should shedule task in windows.

Comment: Task Scheduler is better because it lets you run it under a specific domain account that may not be a user in SQL Server