# How to execute C# code using ETL process

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

I have some C# code and i want that this C# should run exactly at 5 in the evening for that i need to create a job on a server. For creating job i need an ETL package.

How to make ETL of C# code?

Comment: Can you not create a console application and schedule it with the windows scheduler? Building an SSIS package seems like overkill.

Comment: @mikeD. What if i have only have choice of creating SSIS package?

Comment: Then I guess you can't do that but it seems like a strange limitation to have. Though life would be boring without strange limitations.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be to use a script task in the control flow. You can put your C# code there and have it execute. The tricky bit is if your code needs access to non-standard libraries in which case you'll need those deployed to the GAL on the server.

You could also use the execute process task if you have a compiled executable but in that case I would imagine you could just copy it to the server and use windows scheduler.

You can also directly run executables using the SQL agent: [How execute exe file from sql agent or job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754001/how-execute-exe-file-from-sql-agent-or-job)

Comment: Sounds sensible to me. Which approach to use rather depends on what the C# code is actually doing; I certainly wouldn't just from "I need to run some C# code on a server" to the answer "SSIS" without some intervening reasons...