# If I want to execute an executable from a stored procedure, is there any way to do it other than using xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, xp-cmdshell

I have an executable on the server. I want to execute that .exe file in my stored procedure. What is the correct way to do it other than using xp_cmdshell?

Comment: The more important question of course is: why do you want to execute an .exe from a stored proc? If I was your DBA, I  wouldn't let you.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. But maybe it can be done via CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do this, I would create a Job and call it from your stored procedure using sp_start_job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

There is a simple example here on how to create the job to do it: [How execute exe file from sql agent or job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754001/how-execute-exe-file-from-sql-agent-or-job)